# Access table - How to look through table, pull the

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am looking to pull the 2 most recent weeks and return all project numbers for projects that had both a status of 3 for the most recent date they were reported on and anything but 3 for the second most recent date that the respective projects were reported on. I in essence want to take each project number as the unique ID and, for each project, compare the status for its 2 most recent dates reported, and return all projects that are currently a status of 3 in the most recent report date but also in the last report date were not a 3 . Hopefully this makes sense.  The table is below.

```
ID  Report Date Dept    Cost Center     Sub Segment  Status  Project Number
1   1/16/2015   Tech    121                  C&R           1        21046
2   1/21/2015   Tech    122                  Mobil         3        21333
3   1/16/2015   Acct    121                 C&R            2        21333 
4   1/21/2015   Acct    122                 Mobil          1        21046
5   1/16/2015   Fin     121                  C&R           3        24567 
6   1/21/2015   Fin     122                  Mobil         2        24888
7   1/16/2015   Tech    121                   C&R          1        24888
8   1/21/2015   Tech    122                 Mobil          2        24567
9   1/16/2015   Acct    121                 C&R            3        24777
10  1/21/2015   Acct    122                Mobil           1        25555
11  1/16/2015   Fin     121                 C&R            2        25555
12  1/21/2015   Fin     122                Mobil           3        24777
13  1/16/2015   Tech    121                C&R             3        55567
14  1/21/2015   Tech    122                Mobil           3`       55567
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method that uses two conditions in the `where` clause:

```
select pn.project_number
from (select project_number, max(report_date) as maxrd
      from t
      group by project_number
     ) as pn
where 3 = (select t2.status
           from t as t2
           where t2.project_number = t.project_number and t2.date = pn.maxrd
          ) and
      3 <> (select top 1 t2.status
            from t t2
            where t2.project_number = t.project_number and
                  t2.report_date < pn.maxrd
            order by t2.report_date desc
           );
```

The two conditions pretty much follow your logic.  These do assume that there are no duplicates for the project/report date pair.

Comment: The syntax of this works. However when applied to my overall table I get the following error; " at most one record can be returned by this subquery "

Comment: @Lyle . . . That might occur if a project can have multiple records for the same date.  You need to explain how to order them, when this occurs.